# print cck field using node_load

Tags: theming, forms, 6

I found simple code to put inside custom module that prints extra field inside cart view table

```
<?php
function ucaddsku_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'uc_cart_view_form') {
$form['items']['#columns']['model']['cell'] = 'SKU';
        for($i=0;$i<count(uc_cart_get_contents());$i++){            
        $form['items'][$i]['model']['#value'] = node_load($form['items'][$i]['nid']['#value'])->model . ": "; 

    }
}
}
?>
```

How can be any cck field printed like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can print the cck field like this.

```
// Load the node.
$node = node_load($nid);

// Print the fields.
print $node->title;
print $node->field_myfield[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

or a more decent way like this...

```
$myfield = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_myfield');
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7

See this also. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7

Comment: Hi, is it the code same for drupal 6?

Comment: For Drupal 6 use `print $node->field_myfield[0]['value'];`, or loop over `$node->field_myfield` if there are multiple items